# Using Render in my .rb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, html-email, partial

Hi I have some html in a file called (a partial):

```
_quotemail.html.erb
```

I Am sending an email to a user and I want to put this html in the email. I am using mailgun.

I can define my email body like so:

```
body = "text to go in email"
```

which works great but I want to instead include the HTML I have in my quotemail partial.

Whats the best way to do this?